# ASP.NET Core dependency injection: Service resolved at runtime using a Func delegate

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, runtime, asp.net-core, func

I'm trying to inject a service to my controllers but I want to inject a different instance of my service depending of several parameters. Actually for this part it's working, I'm able to do it.

What I want is to load a specific instance of `IRepository<Database>` based on some configuration we get from a configuration file and respecting the DRY rule (don't repeat yourself).

I have these 2 classes:

```
public abstract class FooServicesProvider
{
    public Func<IServiceProvider, IRepository<Database>> DatabaseRepository = provider =>
    {
        return null;
    };
}

public class FooFileSystemServicesProvider : FooServicesProvider
{
    public new Func<IServiceProvider, IRepository<Database>> DatabaseRepository = provider =>
    {
        //Specific code determining which database to use and create a new one if needed
        //our databases are FOLDERS containing some files
        //knowing how chosenDb.FullName is set is not important here
        //[...]
        var databaseRepository = new DatabaseFileSystemRepository(chosenDb.FullName);
        databaseRepository.testProperty = "Foo value";
        return databaseRepository;
    };
}
```

Notice the **new** keyword used to redefine the code of my Func. This is the best way I found because of the Func delegate, I'm very limited, I can't use it in an Interface neither override it.

Now in my *ConfigureServices* method in *Startup.cs* I have this code

```
var fakeConfiguration = "File";
FooServicesProvider servicesProvider = null;
if(fakeConfiguration == "File")
{
    servicesProvider = new FooFileSystemServicesProvider();
}
else
{
    servicesProvider = new AnotherFooServicesProvider();
}
//Here is the tricky part
//This should call FooFileSystemServicesProvider.DatabaseRepository because of the "new" keyword, but it's NOT
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Database>>(servicesProvider.DatabaseRepository);
```

My problem is that the **new** keyword is ignored at runtime and the executed Func is the one declared in my base class instead of the derived one.

If I do this it's working

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Database>>((servicesProvider as FooFileSystemServicesProvider).DatabaseRepository);
```

But I don't want to cast it as I can't know of which type my *servicesProvider* will finally be.

I've tried to get the type of my *servicesProvider* and cast it with its own type but I get compiler error because a Type variable and a Class are different.

So how can I get the good Func executed at runtime? Thanks

Comment: You will have to make the `DatabaseRepository` of the base class `virtual`, and use `override` in the derived type.

Comment: Replace the new keyword by override in your delegate property declaration. Does it work ?

Comment: of course the `new` keyword is being ignored, because `new` only hides the base classes method/property and do not replace or override it...

Comment: As I said, I can't override DatabaseRepository because my _Func_ is a delegate and not a method, it is therefore considered as a property.

Comment: @Tseng neither the second-half of your comment nor your downvote on my question are useful here. I'm stuck because basically what I want is to "override a property" of type `Func`, all my attempts failed that's why I came up with the `new` keyword. I've read several times that it _hides_ the base class property but I indeed misunderstood this word. So I don't think my question lacks of research, it was just an incomprehension.

Comment: @Tseng Anyway, thanks for telling me that I was wrong with my use of the `new` keyword. There was just maybe a nicer way to say it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I finally managed to do what I want, it was actually not that hard, my main problem was to handle the fact that my *Func* was not a method but a delegate. I'm not used to deal with this variable type.

My code in Startup.cs remains unchanged but here is the new code of my custom ServicesProvider

```
public abstract class FooServicesProvider
{
    public Func<IServiceProvider, IRepository<Database>> DatabaseRepository { get; protected set; } 
}

public class FooFileSystemServicesProvider : FooServicesProvider
{
    public FooFileSystemServicesProvider()
    {
        base.DatabaseRepository = GetDatabaseRepository;
    }

    private DatabaseFileSystemRepository GetDatabaseRepository(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //Specific code determining which database to use and create a new one if needed
        //our databases are FOLDERS containing some files
        //knowing how chosenDb.FullName is set is not important here
        //[...]
        var databaseRepository = new DatabaseFileSystemRepository(chosenDb.FullName);
        databaseRepository.testProperty = "Foo value";
        return databaseRepository;
    }        
}
```

Just in case people are wondering: `DatabaseFileSystemRepository` is a class that implements the interface `IRepository<Database>>`

If anyone comes up with a different solution, I'm very curious to know it.